# Adding a view in the Paragraphs Selector

Tags: views, paragraphs, 9

I have a drupal 9 website where I created a View "Homepage - article overview".
On the homepage I have paragraphs enabled (text/image | 2 columns | 4 columns | Full width image).

I want to be able to show that view I created as being on of the paragraphs.
So I can always determine the order of the different pieces.

Is there a module that can tackle this, or do I need to dive in the code?

Comment: Can't tell are you looking for https://www.drupal.org/project/block_field to add a (Views-)block to a paragraph or are you looking for https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews to determine the sort order of the articles in a reference view yourself?

Comment: There are also [Views Reference Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewsreference) and [Viewfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield) modules to reference view displays directly. I've used both with success (Views Reference Field v1.x only), though I think I'd lean toward viewfield at this point.

Comment: @leymannx block_field was exactly what I needed... I spent a few hours google'ing without finding this.. Thanks so much!!!